# SQL compound Key

Tags: sql, compound-key

I am trying to create a table that as a Primary Key uses Values from other tables.My lectures said that this is a compound key (Primary+Foreign) yet I can't seem to be able to find how to initiate one.Can someone try to explain this concept and how to try to implement it?

Answer (score 7):

Consider data which consists of sets of students and courses. When you store it in a DBMS each student (or course) will have an associated unique id, which will be called the primary key of the student (or course)

```
students(id, name, dob)
courses(id, name, credits)
```

To associate students with the courses they are enrolled in you will create a table which looks like this.

```
student_course(student_id, course_id)
```

To create this actually in mysql you would write something like:-

```
CREATE TABLE student_course(student_id INT NOT NULL, 
                            course_id INT NOT NULL, 
                            PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_id),
                            FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(id), 
                            FOREIGN_KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(id))
```